# honey comb devices do not see our app on market

Tags: android

Our app supports android 2.2 up. The app works on android 3.0 emulator. However we received report from honey comb device users that they do not see the app showing up in Market on their device. When they use Market website on PC and select their device to install, they got message of "App not compatible with your device".

Anyone, please advise what we need to do to make the app show in the Market for 3.0 devices. Is it something we need to add in manifest file or something we need to config during the publishing.

June Jorgensen

Comment: Can you say which app it is? Have you checked whether if there are any users who have successfully installed it on an Android phone but can't install it on a Honeycomb tablet using the same account?

Answer (score 1):

Have you set android:xlargeScreens="true" in the supports-screen section of the AndroidManifest.xml?

Have you tried setting the targetSdkVersion in the AndroidManifest.xml to 11 or 12?

Answer (score 1):

Use "aapt dump badging" on your .apk to see the kinds of things in it that are used for filtering.

There is nothing in Honeycomb per-se that would prevent apps from being installed.  However, there are characteristics of current Honeycomb devices that are of interest.  For example, none of them are phones.  Make sure you are not requiring telephony, either explicitly with a  tag, or implicitly by requesting a telephony related permission (again aapt dump badging will tell you about this).